# insert numerical data in appropriate format in textbox

Tags: php

When user insert amount in textbox at that time I want to 
insert amount in this format

```
100.00
1,000.00
```

How to i insert amount in this format in php
periods and commas needs to be their in appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
```

[number format function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

use number format of the variable like this

```
<?php
$number = strip_tags($_POST['number']);
echo number_format($number,2);
```

the second parameter in `number_format()` is upto which level you want a value. if you want upto 2 decimal places then it will be 2.
if you want only integer the type cast it to `int()` this will help you . :-)

Comment: This function name is: intval() - not int(). see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: @Adam Yeah you're right, but while you're doing typecasting you can also do like this
`<?php`
`$name = 123.89;`
`echo (int)$name;`
`?>`

Comment: It's OK but I'm not sure but if (int)$name is the same as int($name)